# Convert from binary back to its string value in Java

Tags: java, string, binary

Currently, I have a String with the value "0100100001101001" (this is binary for the word 'Hi'). I'm trying to figure out how to take that string and convert it back into the word "Hi"

I used

```
String s = "Hi";   
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();   
StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();   
for (byte b : bytes)   
{      
    int val = b;      
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)      
    {         
        binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);         
        val <<= 1;      
    }         
}   
s = binary.toString();
```

found on: 
[Convert A String (like testing123) To Binary In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917163/convert-a-string-like-testing123-to-binary-in-java)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *""0100100001101001" (this is binary for the word 'Hi')"* ***In what character set?*** (Yes, I know, ASCII and most others, because it *happens* that "H" and "i" are fairly common amongst them. But the point stands.)

Comment: Why can't you just undo what you have done?

Answer (score 2):

Something like..

```
BigInteger val = new BigInteger("0100100001101001", 2);
String hi = new String(val.toByteArray());
```

Comment: +1 It might be appropriate to include an encoding specification when converting bytes to a string; e.g.: `String hi = new String(val.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");`. There's also the small problem of byte ordering, but OP is on his own for this.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, for variety. Uses `(char)` casting. Take `s` to be the binary `String`:

```
String result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i += 8) {
    result += (char) Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i, i + 8), 2);
}
```