# Convert String / char into specified-digit binary string and vice versa in java

Tags: java, string, binary, char

I'm trying to convert a string (or a single char) into given number of digits binary string in java. Assume that given number is 5, so a string "zx~q" becomes 01101, 10110, 11011, 10011 (I' ve made up the binaries). However, I need to revert these binaries into "abcd" again. If given number changes, the digits (so the binaries) will change.

Anyone has an idea?

PS: `Integer.toBinaryString()` changes into an 8-digit binary array.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211705/binary-to-text-in-java

Comment: @Tuğcem Oral Try my solution it will help you.

Comment: @TGMCians given string might not come up with hexadecimal radix, it might contain any ascii character

Comment: Actually, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917163/convert-a-string-like-testing123-to-binary-in-java) post answers half of my problem. But I couldnt decode the generated binary into desired char.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `Integer.toString(int i, int radix)` and `Integer.parseInt(string s, int radix)` would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve like this.

To convert **abcd** to 1010101111001101,

```
class Demo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        String str = "abcd";
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i)), 16);
            String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(number);
            System.out.print(binary);
        }
    }
}
```

To convert the 1010101111001101 to abcd

```
String str = "1010101111001101";
String binary = Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(str,2));
System.out.print(binary);
```

Comment: @SirPentor, Integer.parseInt takes radix for second parameter. However, the desired string to convert to given-digited binary might be like "zz~java". "abcd" wasnt a good example.

Comment: What if there is a space in between ?