# convert string to binary and take one's complement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert string to binary and take one's complement, after that display the string again. i have seen a couples of related post such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736533/how-do-you-convert-a-string-to-ascii-to-binary-in-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659787/convert-string-to-binary-zeros-and-ones) and i'm follow the official work where have been posted in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396849/convert-binary-to-ascii-and-vice-versa), in the below code after run the code its showing error **AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'**. i'm using python 3.6

the below code is :

```
import binascii

def text_to_bits(text, encoding='utf-8', errors='surrogatepass'):
    bits = bin(int(binascii.hexlify(text.encode(encoding, errors)), 16))[2:]
    return bits.zfill(8 * ((len(bits) + 7) // 8))

def text_from_bits(bits, encoding='utf-8', errors='surrogatepass'):
    n = int(bits, 2)
    return int2bytes(n).decode(encoding, errors)

def int2bytes(i):
    hex_string = '%x' % i
    n = len(hex_string)
    return binascii.unhexlify(hex_string.zfill(n + (n & 1)))
your_string='hello'
b=your_string.encode('ascii', 'strict')
text_to_bits(b)
```

is there a way after convert it to binary to take one's complement of it and display the string again?

Comment: You are "encode"ing twice. Omit one.

Comment: can you explain sir ? i didn't get you. thanks

Comment: There is a much easier way to [do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18815890/8150685) in python3.

Answer (score 0):

No need to convert your string into unicode (encode).
Your functions work very well.
Look at the code below:

```
your_string='hello'
#b=your_string.encode('ascii', 'strict')
b = text_to_bits(your_string)
print(b)
t = text_from_bits(b)
print(t)
```

Result:

```
0110100001100101011011000110110001101111
hello
```

Comment: thanks sir, i think you are using python 2, in python 3 it's showing TypeError: 'str' object is not callable , so i was trying to solve the problem by convert str to bytes first like your_string.encode('ascii', 'strict') , but showing another error message is AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: I am using 3.6.5 python --version
Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.

Comment: i'm using 3.6.4 and still not able to run the code give me same error

Answer (score 0):

If supporting ASCII is enough, you can do this:

```
a="Hello World!"
b="".join(bin(ord(x)^255)[2:] for x in a)
print(b)
c="".join(chr(int(b[x:x+8],2)^255) for x in range(0,len(b),8))
print(c)
```

> ```
> 101101111001101010010011100100111001000011011111101010001001000010001101100100111001101111011110
> ```
>
> Hello World!

since ASCII codes are below 128, `someASCII ^ 255` (the one's complement) is always going to be a 8-bit number (the most significant bit gets set). `bin()` prepends a `0b` prefix, that is what the `[2:]` gets rid of.

If you need it for generic bytes, some padding magic has to be applied, like

```
b="".join(("0000000"+bin(ord(x))[2:])[-8:] for x in a)
```

Comment: thx sir for good explain. but which version python are you using? i'm trying your code in python 3.6 and showing b="".join(bin(ord(x)^255)[2:] for x in a)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: @david I was using 3.6.3 in particular. It seems to work fine on Ideone too: https://ideone.com/wqwVPk

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you could do this easier:

```
st = "hello world"
my_binary = ' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in st)
print(my_binary)

original = ''.join(chr(int(X[:8], 2)) for X in my_binary.split())
print(original)
```

References:

- [Convert Binary String to String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40559005/8150685)
- [Convert String to Binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815820/convert-string-to-binary-in-python/18815890#18815890)

Then just do twos-compliment on the string with something like:

```
def binary_str_twos(bin_str):
    twos = []
    first_one = True
    # twos compliment
    for char in reversed(bin_str):
        if char == ' ':
            twos.append(char)
        elif char == '1':
            twos.append('1' if first_one else '0')
            if first_one:
                first_one = False
        else:
            twos.append('0' if first_one else '1')

    return ''.join(reversed(twos))
```

Note that this isn't as efficient as working with binary only.

-- Edit --
Working in 8-bit binary without spaces:

```
st = "hello world"
my_binary = ''.join(format(ord(x), '08b') for x in st)
print(my_binary)

original = ''.join(chr(int(my_binary[i:i+8], 2)) for i in range(0, len(my_binary), 8))
print(original)
```

Comment: good job sir,thanks, just one thing , how i can remove the spaces in between the bits? in the result shown 1101000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1110111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100  ? i want fully series binary such like (11010001100101110110011011001101111100000111011111011111110010 11011001100100 )

Comment: You can either change the logic to use `''.join(...)` instead of `' '.join(...)` or just do `print(''.join(my_binary.split()))`. Though option 1 would be faster in the long run.

Comment: thx again sir, i follow what you said , i got this output (1101000110010111011001101100110111110000011101111101111111001011011001100100 Ñ) so the word , hello world display!

Comment: @david See my update for working without spaces. ( You may want to work with 16 bits instead of 8 (`' '.join(format(ord(x), '016b')`

Comment: @Error-Syntavtical Remorse , i appreciate your perfect work. thank you sir.