# Convert from binary to ASCII Fortran

Tags: fortran, ascii, gfortran, non-ascii-characters, fortran95

i try to convert a input_file.binary in a numbers  output_file.txt with a fortran (or if someone have another idea: pyton, java, c++ ...). The ascii file is a 11 rows and N columns file with only numbers (i.e.: 1e-21, 0.0, 1 .... ).

I try this post [ASCii to BInary Conversion Program in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867918/ascii-to-binary-conversion-program-in-java) but this is a bit different respect to my idea: i want to read the binary and write an output_file.dat so i try with this fortran code:

```
 program binary
 implicit none

    integer :: i, n
    real, allocatable :: data(:,:)
    open(20,file="input.dat",status="unknown",err=88)
    n = 0
    do
        read(20,*,end=1)
        n = n+1
    end do
    1 rewind(20)
    allocate(data(n,11))
    OPEN(10, file="output_file.txt")
    do i = 1, n
        read(20,*) data(i,:)
        write(10,*) data(i,:)
    end do
    close(20)

 end program binary
```

when i want to inspect the file with `nano file.binary` the output is like that:

^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^C^@^@^A�^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^A^@^R�M0wc�6�7�^@^@^@^FA0^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^‌​@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@�e^A^@^@^@^B+�^[2/[��^@^@^@^FAI�#$

I can compile the program but when i try to run it i have the follow error message:

forrtl: severe (59): list-directed I/O syntax error, unit 20, file /.../input.dat
Image PC Routine Line Source 
ascii 0805D0AA Unknown Unknown Unknown 
ascii 0805B14D Unknown Unknown Unknown 
ascii 0804A1EA Unknown Unknown Unknown 
ascii 08049E67 Unknown Unknown Unknown 
libc.so.6 B75CF4D3 Unknown Unknown Unknown

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: If the `ascii` file has numbers as text then what is the purpose of re-creating a text file? If the file has binary numbers then it is not `ascii`. Please clarify, or show the contents of `input.dat`.

Comment: when i try to open the input.dat file with the 'nano input.dat' command this is the contents:

Comment: ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^C^@^@^A�^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^A^@^R�M0wc�6�7�^@^@^@^FA0^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@�e^A^@^@^@^B+�^[2/[��^@^@^@^FAI�#$


lots of this values but when i open this whit a program (swiftvis) that convert ascii to txt i see the right numbers.

Comment: Please update your question. The input file type is binary and _not_ `ASCII`.

Comment: Try to open it with http://www.hhdsoftware.com/free-hex-editor and dislay as float. This will confirm what format the binary file is in.

Comment: I believe you will have to use `stream` acces to the file you read. This way you read it as a normal `formatted` (i.e. ASCII) file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write *The ascii file is a 11 rows and N columns* and then allocate an array like this:

```
allocate(data(n,11))
```

This makes `data` an `n`-row, `11`-column array, which seems to transpose the dimensions from your file.  If you were reading the input file element-by-element that probably wouldn't cause the run-time system to raise an error though it might leave you with the transpose of the array you want.

However, you read the input file row-by-row.  As you have explained matters that file should have 11 rows of data but your program tries to read (and write) `n` rows.  Again, there's nothing actually wrong with your program to this point, though it perhaps doesn't do what you expect it to.

But your program expects each row in the input file to provide 11 values and I guess that it doesn't, leading to the error you report.

Comment: Yes, this is an error that i didn't see and now i check and when i try to run the program "./ascii" i receive the follow error:

Comment: forrtl: severe (59): list-directed I/O syntax error, unit 20, file /.../input.dat
Image              PC        Routine            Line        Source             
ascii              0805D0AA  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
ascii              0805B14D  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
ascii              0804A1EA  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
ascii              08049E67  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc.so.6          B75CF4D3  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown

Comment: Never put anything in a comment that you want someone to read, especially not code or output that requires careful formatting for readability.  Edit your question.

Comment: finally i solve my problem with a f.90 code. So this post could be closed. Thanks to everybody !!!