# Converting a string to binary [Java]

Tags: java, string, binary

Let's say I have the following string:

```
String s = "Hello, stackoverflow"
```

How would I convert that into a binary number (0s and 1s)? Here's the trick: I'm not allowed to use built-in methods for the conversion. It has to be done mathematically. I have no idea where to begin. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit 1: I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917163/convert-a-string-like-testing123-to-binary-in-java) and people suggested using getBytes(string), charset UTF-8, and Integer.toBinaryString. I'm not allowed to use any of these methods for conversion. I haven't heard of 36-base either.

Comment: dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917163/convert-a-string-like-testing123-to-binary-in-java

Comment: NO built in methods, not even `byte[] b = s.getBytes();`?

Comment: no getByes, charset UTF-8, or toBinaryString

Comment: Surely, we can use `s.toCharArray()`, or at least `s.charAt(int)`?

Answer (score 3):

This seems a bit unfair because we can't use:

```
byte[] b = s.getBytes();
```

This is the shortest solution to your problem, but since you aren't supposed to use that, here's a *bad* approach:

**Using [`String#charAt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-):**

```
String s = "Hello, stackoverflow";
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++ ) {
    int characterASCII = s.charAt(i);
    // Automatic type casting as 'char' is a type of 'int'
    buf.append(Integer.toBinaryString(characterASCII));
    // or:
    // buf.append(characterASCII, 2);
    // or - custom method:
    // buf.append(toBinary(characterASCII));
}
System.out.println("answer : " + buf.toString());
```

And if you decide to use `toBinary(int)` method, here it is:

```
public static final String toBinary (int num) {
    char[] buf = new char[32];
    int charPos = 32;
    do {
        buf[--charPos] = i & 1;
        i >>>= 1;
    } while (i != 0);
    return new String(buf);
}
```

Or if even this is not allowed, you'd better make your own solution. :-)

Answer (score 2):

First get bytes form string using `getByte()` function then use  `Integer.toBinaryString(byte)` function. & thats it.

NOTE:~ Make sure `Integer.toBinaryString(byte)` accepts int(or in this case byte not all.) so you have to pass byte by byte.(may be for loop.)

**Edited :~** 
what you can do is parse string char by char & for each char you can get ascii value using.

```
int tempChar = (int)ch;
```

Then simpley use this.

```
Integer.toString(tempChar,2);
```

try this.

```
string finalString = "";
for(int i = 0;i<myStr.length;i++){
    int tempChar = (int)ch;
    finalString = finalString + Integer.toString(tempChar,2);//& this is not allowed then now only you need to create function for integer to binary conversion.
}
System.out.println("Your byte String is"+finalString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:-

```
String s = "Hello, stackoverflow"
byte[] bytes = str.getBytes(s);
```

You may check the [getBytes() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29) in java

> Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the named charset,
>   storing the result into a new byte array.
>
> The behavior of this method when this string cannot be encoded in the
>   given charset is unspecified. The CharsetEncoder class should be used
>   when more control over the encoding process is required.

If you want the bits for each byte:

```
for(int i=0; i<array.length;i++){
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(0x100 + array[i]).substring(1));
}
```