# Character strings to binary string - why are some characters multi-byte?

Tags: java, string, binary, ascii

This code is supposed to convert a character strings to binary ones, but with a few strings, it returns a `String` with 16 binary digits, not 8 as I expected them to be.

```
public class aaa {        
    public static void main(String argv[]){
        String nux="ª";
        String nux2="Ø";
        String nux3="(";
        byte []bites = nux.getBytes();
        byte []bites2 = nux2.getBytes();
        byte []bites3 = nux3.getBytes();
               System.out.println(AsciiToBinary(nux));
               System.out.println(AsciiToBinary(nux2));
               System.out.println(AsciiToBinary(nux3));
               System.out.println("number of bytes :"+bites.length);
               System.out.println("number of bytes :"+bites2.length);
               System.out.println("number of bytes :"+bites3.length);


    }

    public static String AsciiToBinary(String asciiString){  

          byte[] bytes = asciiString.getBytes();  
          StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();  
          for (byte b : bytes)  
          {  
             int val = b;  
             for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)  
             {  
                binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);  
                val <<= 1;  
             }  
             binary.append(' ');
          }  
          return binary.toString();  
    } 

}
```

in the first two strings, I don't understand why they return 2 bytes, since they are single-character strings.

Compiled here to: https://ideone.com/AbxBZ9

This returns:

```
11000010 10101010 
11000011 10011000 
00101000 
number of bytes :2
number of bytes :2
number of bytes :1
```

I am using this code: [Convert A String (like testing123) To Binary In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917163/convert-a-string-like-testing123-to-binary-in-java)

NetBeans IDE 8.1

Comment: What makes you think that the number of characters is the same as the number of bytes? There's tens of thousands of symbols out there. They can't all be represented with a single byte. It strongly depends on the encoding you use, but multi-byte encodings are rather common.

Comment: Note that `getBytes` can take an argument for the character set you want to use.

Comment: The ASCII code only has 256 symbols (one per possible byte value). The lower 128 symbols are the same as UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, and other popular encodings; so as long as you do not use non-english symbols, you may think that everything is just ASCII.

Comment: There are more possible characters than possible byte values. So clearly not all characters can be encoded in a single byte.

Answer (score 6):

A character is not always 1-byte long. Think about it - many languages, such as Chinese or Japanese, have thousands of characters, how would you map those characters to bytes?

You are using [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) (one of the many, many ways of mapping characters to bytes) - looking up a character table for UTF-8, and searching for the sequence `11000010 10101010`, I arrive at

```
U+00AA  ª   11000010 10101010
```

Which is the UTF-8 encoding for `ª`. UTF-8 is often the default character encoding (charset) for Java -- but you cannot rely on this. That is why you should always [specify a charset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html) when converting [strings to bytes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.nio.charset.Charset%29) or [vice-versa](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)

Answer (score -1):

you can understand why some character are two bytes by running this simple code

```
    // integer - binary 
    System.out.println(Byte.MIN_VALUE);             
    // -128 - 0b11111111111111111111111110000000

    System.out.println(Byte.MAX_VALUE);             
    // 127 - 0b1111111

    System.out.println((int) Character.MIN_VALUE);  
    // 0   - 0b0

    System.out.println((int) Character.MAX_VALUE);  
    // 65535 - 0b1111111111111111
```

as you can see ,we can show `Byte.MAX_VALUE` with just **`7 bits` or `1 byte (01111111)`**

if you cast `Character.MIN_VALUE` to integer, it will be : `0`
 
we can show it's binary format with **`one bit` or `1 byte (00000000)`**!

**but what about `Character.MAX_VALUE` ?**

in binary format it's
**`1111111111111111`** which is **`65535`**  in decimal format
 and can be shown with **`2 bytes (11111111 11111111)`.**

so characters which their decimal format is  between `0 and 65535` can be shown with **`1 or 2 bytes`**.

hope you understand.

Comment: Your code only proves that `Character.MAX_VALUE` requires at least 2 bytes, but does not explain why some chars fit in a byte and others don't. The binary value of Byte.MIN_VALUE is also not that useful (1073741792 is -128 only when interpreted as 4-byte two's complement. In that sense, 0b10000000 is clearer & shorter: -128 in 1-byte two's complement).

Comment: So why you don't edit my post,I said what I know, instead of down voting my or other posts,try to edit them,we are here to share our knowledge,I did now is your turn :)

Comment: If you edit your post so that it answers the question, I will be happy to change my vote. I have not looked at your other posts. You are responsible for editing your own posts if they are wrong or don't answer the question: share knowledge, but take responsibility to make sure it is accurate.