# Convert ASCII characters to binary (7-bit)

Tags: java

I need to convert  ASCII characters  to  (7-bit) binary. 
I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917163/convert-a-string-like-testing123-to-binary-in-java), but it gives me the binary value in 8 bits, meanwhile i want it to be in 7 bits. For instance:

`C`  should be `1000011`

`CC` should be `10000111000011`

`%`   should be `0100101`

So, I changed the code to:

```
String s = "%";
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    int val =  bytes[j];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
        val <<= 1;
    }
    binary.append("");
}

System.out.println("'" + s + "' to binary: " + binary);
```

and **it complains with:**

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

in the line:

```
int val =  bytes[j];
```

**To highlight:**

I used

```
 for(int j=0;j<7;j++)
    int val =  bytes[j];
```

instead of

`for (byte b : bytes) 
          int val = b;`

Comment: `"%".getBytes()` is returning **bytes**, not **bits**. Your `bytes` array will only have 1 element in it (at index `0`).

Comment: byte, being integer types IS BINARY. You want not convert, but print it in binary form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 changes in your code below :

```
        String s = "%";
        byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
        StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
        for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
            int val = bytes[j];
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                val <<= 1;
                binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("'" + s + "' to binary: " + binary);
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your first `for` loop from:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
```

To:

```
for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
```

You want this outer loop to loop over all of the elements of `bytes`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code which should give you a hint; it takes each character as a byte, then walks along each of the least significant 7 bits, using a bitmask. Just add your string builder code;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "A";
    byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();

    for (int bytePos = 0; bytePos < bytes.length; ++bytePos) {
        byte b = bytes[bytePos];
        byte mask = 0b1000000;
        while (mask > 0) {
            System.out.println(b & mask);
            mask /= 2;
        }
    }
}
```